# Custom theme not working after upgrading 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p3

Tags: theme, magento2.4.3, custom-theme

After updating to version 2.4.3-p3 our custom theme isn't working anymore.
The theme has the default Luma theme as parent.
After generating static content it does generate the custom theme files (can see theme at pub/static/frontend/< vendor >/< theme >).

Design settings show that the custom theme is selected (Content -> configuration), however on the frontend the Luma theme is displayed, in stead of the custom child theme.
All files are loaded from /frontend/Magento/Luma.

Cleared the caches:
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/code/*

No errors during the static content deployment, or in the system.log, anywhere else I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the theme defined for the correct store? Is the applied theme correct? https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/apply-storefront/

Comment: The store I expected it to be had the correct theme selected.
However after upgrading our custom multistore logic was missing, so a different store was loaded at the frontend, which as you commented did not have the right theme applied. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem! Glad you've fixed it.